# Не переведено сообщение о том, что указанный вопрос был заблокирован по причине спама или оскорбления

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, заблокированные-вопросы

В вопросе [Парсинг irr, avito, auto [удален]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/561474/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-irr-avito-auto) не переведено уведомление в заголовке:

> This question was marked as spam or rude or abusive and is therefore not shown

И в теле вопроса:

> This question was marked as spam or rude or abusive and is therefore
>   not shown - you can see [the revision history](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/561474/revisions) for details.

[image: Вопрос в ленте]

---

[image: Просмотр вопроса]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поскольку в русском языке нет большой разницы между причинами закрытия "мат" и "оскорбления", я предлагаю использовать чуть измененный старый перевод:

> This question was marked as spam or rude or abusive and is therefore
>   not shown

> Данный вопрос был отмечен как содержащий спам или оскорбления, поэтому
>   его не показывают

---

> This question was marked as spam or rude or abusive and is therefore
>   not shown - you can see the revision history for details.

> Данный вопрос был отмечен как спам или оскорбление и поэтому не
>   отображается — для получения подробной информации посмотрите
>   историю правок.

Comment: Весьма иронично, когда правок не было и ссылки на историю поэтому тоже нет. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, но ссылка-то есть в теле сообщения. Хотя вроде помню, что раньше не было.

Comment: И у нас нет двух разных причин для мата и оскорблений. Вы про спам?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, вот об этой части фразы: `as spam or rude or abusive` или же в переводе на русский: `как спам, грубое/оскорбительное высказывание, мат`. Да, о сообщении появившемся в примере из вопроса.

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю быть более последовательными и использовать сочетание "неприемлемое содержимое", как это было сделано в сообщении об использованной тревоге.

> This question was marked as spam or rude or abusive and is therefore not shown

> Содержимое этого вопроса было неприемлемым, поэтому он скрыт

---

А вот в детальном описании можно расписать подробнее:

> This question was marked as spam or rude or abusive and is therefore not shown - you can see the revision history for details.

> Этот вопрос был отмечен как спам или оскорбление, поэтому он скрыт. Если вы всё равно хотите его просмотреть, загляните в [историю правок](//).